# Would PCA work for boolean (binary) data types?

Tags: pca, data-visualization, binary-data, dimensionality-reduction, correspondence-analysis

I want to reduce the dimensionality of higher order systems and capture most of the covariance on a preferably 2 dimensional or 1 dimensional field. I understand this can be done via principal component analysis, and I have used PCA in many scenarios. However, I have never used it with boolean data types, and I was wondering if it is meaningful to do PCA with this set. So for example, pretend I have qualitative or descriptive metrics, and I assign a "1" if that metric is valid for that dimension, and a "0" if it is not (binary data). So for example, pretend you are trying to compare the Seven Dwarfs in Snow White. We have:

Doc, Dopey, Bashful, Grumpy, Sneezy, Sleepy and Happy, and you want to arrange them based on qualities, and did so as is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  & Lactose\ Intolerant & A \ Honor\ Roll & Athletic       & Wealthy \\
Doc & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
Dopey & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Bashful & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
Grumpy & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
Sneezy & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
Sleepy & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Happy  & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So for example Bashful is lactose intolerant and not on the A honor roll. This is a purely hypothetical matrix, and my real matrix will have many more descriptive columns. My question is, would it still be appropriate to do PCA on this matrix as a means of finding the similarity between individuals?

Comment: This question is (almost) a duplicate of [that one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16331/3277). PCA may be done on binary/boolean data, but doing factor analysis (including PCA "as if" it is FA) on such data [is problematic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/154250/3277).

Comment: PCA on binary data such as yours ("present" vs "absent") would normally be performed without centering the variables because there is no reason to suggest the origin (the reference point) other than the original 0. So, instead of covariance- or correlation-based PCA we arrive at [SSCP- or cosine-based](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) one. Such analysis is very similar, almost equivalent to Multiple Correspondence analysis (= Homogeneity analysis) which could be the choice for you.

Comment: `a means of finding the similarity between individuals`. But this task is for a Cluster analysis, not PCA.

Comment: Short answer: linear PCA (if it is taken as dimensionality reduction technique and not latent variable technique as factor analysis) can be used for scale (metrical) or binary data. Plain (linear) PCA should not be used, however, with ordinal data or nominal data - unless these data are turned into metrical or binary (e.g. dummy) some way.

Comment: @ttnphns PCA can be viewed as a way to cluster variables. Also, PCA and cluster analysis can be used [in sequence](http://factominer.free.fr/docs/HCPC_husson_josse.pdf)

Comment: @Antoine, I definitely concur with your last part, but no so readily with the first. If I were to take strick stance I'd say it is factor analysis not PCA which could be seen as a way to cluster variables See, e.g. bullet 8 at the bottom [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/95106/3277). PCA does not explain _specifically_ associations between variables.

Comment: Here is a 2020 reference for an R implementation of PCA on binary data:
https://github.com/andland/logisticPCA
https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06112

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a relatively recent technique for automatic structure extraction from categorical variable data (this includes binary). The method is called CorEx from Greg van Steeg from University of Southern California. The idea is to use the notion of Total Correlation based on the entropy measures. It is appealing due to its simplicity and no tuning of large number of hyperparameters.

The paper about hierarchical representations (the most recent, builds on the top of the previous measures).
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7404.pdf

Comment: @AlvinNunez You're welcome! The python implementation can be found on GitHub https://github.com/gregversteeg/CorEx Really easy to get your data in and see what comes out.

Comment: -1 because this does not seem to actually answer the question (despite being accepted by the OP)

Answer (score 17):

You can also use Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA), which is an extension of principal component analysis when the variables to be analyzed are categorical instead of quantitative (which is the case here with your binary variables). See for instance [Husson et al. (2010)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150615153716/http://factominer.free.fr/docs/HCPC_husson_josse.pdf), or [Abdi and Valentin (2007)](http://wwwpub.utdallas.edu/%7Eherve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf). An excellent R package to perform MCA (and hierarchical clustering on PCs) is [FactoMineR](http://factominer.free.fr/classical-methods/multiple-correspondence-analysis.html).

Comment: An interesting answer, I'd rather agree with it. It will be great asset to it  if you explain in more detail the phenomenon of the `inflation of the feature space` and why it would occur in PCA and not in MCA.

Comment: I misunderstood the `inflation of the feature space` phenomenon. It seems to be coming into play when going from CA to MCA, but is not an inherent issue of PCA. I am going to remove my answer when you have read this comment. Thanks for making me realize that.

Comment: I don't think that you have to remove the answer. MCA is one of right choices, for me, and your answer is all right.

Comment: I added back the answer because I think MCA might be helpful here, but I removed the discussion about the inflation of the feature space since it did not seem to be relevant

Comment: How would the result of MCA on binary data differ from the result of a PCoA with a distance measure appropriate for binary data like Jaccard or simple matching?

Comment: -1 because this does not seem to actually answer the question

Answer (score 13):

If you think of PCA as an exploratory technique to give you a way to visualise the relationships between variables (and in my opinion this is the only way to think about it) then yes, there is no reason why you can't put in binary variables. For example, here is a biplot of your data

[image]

It seems reasonably useful. For example, you can see that Doc and Bashful are very similar; that HR is rather unlike the three other variables; Sleepy and Sneezy are very dissimilar, etc.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your answer. Are you trying to say we can apply PCA directly on rank deficient matrices? SVD is not applicable to binary matrices. Can you write down the linear algebraic proof of your method? Would be interesting to see how it is done

Answer (score 10):

Although PCA is often used for binary data, it is argued that PCA assumptions are not appropriate for binary or count data (see e.g. [Collins 2002](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2078-a-generalization-of-principal-components-analysis-to-the-exponential-family.pdf) for an explanation) and generalizations exists: the strategy is similar in spirit to the development of generalized linear models to perform regression analysis for data belonging to the exponential family.

An implementation in R of different methods can be found in the `logisticPCA` package, and a tutorial [in this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logisticPCA/vignettes/logisticPCA.html).

Ref. Collins, M., Dasgupta, S., & Schapire, R. E. (2002). A generalization of principal components analysis to the exponential family. In Advances in neural information processing systems (pp. 617-624).